# How to plot weird timestamp in Matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot, matlab-figure

I have a rather simple task. I just simply need to do something like that

```
plot(stampy{1:5},data{2}(1:5))
```

However, with  **stampy{1:5}** I have five separate **ans** and **data{2}(1:5)** seems to be alright for plotting. i have tried to **loop** smth like that

```
cc=zeros(1,10);
for i=1:10
     cc(i) = stampy{i}
end
```

But it did not work. I don't know, it seems to be a very simple task.
Can anybody suggest the solution ?
I have data in this form:

```
>> stampy{1:5}
ans =
21-Sep-2016 05:52:00
ans =
21-Sep-2016 05:53:00  
ans =
21-Sep-2016 05:54:00
ans =
21-Sep-2016 05:55:00
ans =
21-Sep-2016 05:56:00
```

and

```
>> data{2}(1:5)

ans =

  -32.3750
  -25.0000
  -25.0000
  -25.0000
  -25.0000
```

Comment: It seems like you've not accepted any of the answers on ***all of your questions***. Take some time and mark the most helpful answer that solves your problem on all of your questions as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/335102) by clicking the **`✓`** on the left side of the answer to turn it green. You can also [upvote the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/335102) if you like by clicking  **`▲`** . Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to convert each of your dates to a date number and use *this* as the x axis. You can then use [`datetick`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) to specify the format to use for your tick marks. This has the benefits that it works on most any version of MATLAB and it handles non-uniformly spaced dates.

```
plot(datenum(stampy), data{2}(1:5))
datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to plot a time axis, you can use a `datetime` type of variable:

```
% the following line converts stampy to a time vector:
sy = datetime(stampy,'InputFormat','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
plot(sy,data{2}(1:5))
```

Comment: While it's certainly more feature-rich, you don't *need* to use the `datetime` class. Functions like [`datetick`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) existed long before the `datetime` class was introduced in R2014b.

Comment: @excaza this was just a bad wording, I changed it now.

Answer (score 2):

Just plot your data and rename the Xticks as follows:

```
plot(data{2}(1:5));
set(gca,'XTick',1:5,'XTickLabel',{stampy{1:5}});
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Much appreciate your advice both of you.
worked for me!!! Do yougyus maybe have an ide how to bend timestap angle ?? THX

>> plot(data{2}(1:5));
>> set(gca,'XTick',1:5,'XTickLabel',{stampy{1:5}});

Comment: @user2156115 `set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 45);` This will rotate the xticks by an angle of 45.

Comment: >> matlab
Error using hg.axes/set
The name 'XTickLabelRotation' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'axes'.

Error in matlab (line 20)
set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 45);

Comment: I don't get any such error, and this is the output that I am getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TisQr.jpg

Comment: @user2156115 `XTickLabelRotation` was introduced in Matlab R2014b, maybe you have an earlier version?

Comment: @user2156115 Which version of MATLAB are you using? There is this submission (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722-rotate-tick-label) at FileExchange that you can use

Comment: yes guys you were right I am having earlier version :)